# wsimport - unable to parse remote wsdl (connection refused)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsimport

When trying to get java class definitions from remote WSDL on my Linux machine I get this error:

```
wsimport http://172.28.0.22:8090/Service

parsing WSDL...

[ERROR]         Unable to parse "http://localhost:8090/Service?wsdl=wsdl0" : Connection refused
  line 1 of http://172.28.0.22:8090/Service

[ERROR]         Unable to parse "http://localhost:8090/Service?wsdl=wsdl0" : Connection refused

Failed to read the WSDL document: http://172.28.0.22:8090/Service, because 
1) could not find the document; 
2) the document could not be read; 
3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>.

[ERROR] Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):

http://172.28.0.22:8090/Service
 At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.

        Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

When getting `curl http://172.28.0.22:8090/Service` into console I receive correct WSDL file with main  tag. This service does not require any authorization.

What am I doing wrong? Why wsimport changes URL to localhost?

EDIT: `curl`ing this URL gives this output (I have dotted private data):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="Service" targetNamespace="..." xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="..." xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:i0="..." xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
    <wsdl:import namespace="..." location="http://localhost:8090/Service?wsdl=wsdl0" />
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="...">
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8090/Service?xsd=xsd0" namespace="..." />
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8090/Service?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
            <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:8090/Service?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Service" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="Service_...">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:..." />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="Service">
        <wsdl:operation name="....">
            <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="..." message="..." />
            <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="..." message="..." />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:service name="Service">
        <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_Service" binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_Service">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8090/Service" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: What does the WSDL look like? Does it refer to the URL `http://localhost:8090/Service?wsdl=wsdl0`?

Comment: @Jesper I have edited my post

Comment: So there is the answer to your question "why does wsimport change the URL to localhost": because in the WSDL, there are URLs with `localhost` as the hostname. This is a problem in the webservice that is sending you the WSDL.